# List of Objects pointing to the last one

Tags: java, list, object, garbage-collection, weak-references

I have been looking for similar issues but I couldn't find an answer (Or I didn't type the right key words)

I am using this Java kohonen neural network library : [JKNNL](http://jknnl.sourceforge.net/)

I am instantiating a neural network (DefaultNetwork Class) from my main class. The network has neurons (KohonenNeuron Class) with an array of weights. In the network's constructor, there is a for loop that instantiates an array of KohonenNeuron objects with random weights. The problem is at the end of the loop, all the neurons have the same weights (the same as the last object instanciated). It seems like all the KohonenNeuron refrences only one object. What am I doing wrong? 
I tried using dynamic lists and also divided the instanciation into declaration and instanciation. Nothing seems to work.

Here is the call I make from my main class:

```
MatrixTopology topology = new MatrixTopology(65,10);
      double[] maxWeight = //MAX WEIGHT INIT
      DefaultNetwork network = new DefaultNetwork(33,maxWeight,topology);

      System.out.println("====== NETWORK RANDOM CREATION - FROM MAIN ======== : \n" + network ); //THIS IS WHERE IT GETS WRONG
```

Here is the DefaultNetwork constructor I am calling:

```
public DefaultNetwork(int weightNumber, double[] maxWeight, TopologyModel topology) {
    this.topology = topology;
    int numberOfNeurons = topology.getNumbersOfNeurons(); //650 : Check !
    neuronList = new KohonenNeuron[numberOfNeurons]; //List of 650 : Check ! 
    for (int i=0; i<numberOfNeurons; i++){

        neuronList[i] = new KohonenNeuron(weightNumber,maxWeight,null) ;

        System.out.println("FROM DEFAULT NETWORK CLASS (random init!!) \n");
        System.out.println("neuron " + i +": " + neuronList[i] + " \n"); 
    }
}
```

At this point , at each iteration, it prints a neuron with a different weight..
But, in the debug, I see that every iteration, all the neurons take the weights of the last neuron instantiated.

And here is the KohonenNeuron contructor I am calling:

```
 public KohonenNeuron(int weightNumber, double[] maxWeight, ActivationFunctionModel activationFunction){
    if(weightNumber == maxWeight.length){
        Random rand = new Random();
        weight = new double[weightNumber];
        for(int i=0; i< weightNumber; i++){
            weight[i] = rand.nextDouble() * maxWeight[i];
        }
    }
    this.activationFunction = activationFunction;
}
```

When I run my code:

====== NETWORK RANDOM CREATION - FROM MAIN ======== : 
Neuron number 1: [ 839.7982035619445, 207.3469810016878, 296.9038782440716, 203.37270988484246, 469.36732048088726, 692.6075370855006, 425.4782925339686, [...] ]
Neuron number 2: [ 839.7982035619445, 207.3469810016878, 296.9038782440716, 203.37270988484246, 469.36732048088726, 692.6075370855006, 425.4782925339686, [...] ]
.
.
.
Neuron number 649: [ 839.7982035619445, 207.3469810016878, 296.9038782440716, 203.37270988484246, 469.36732048088726, 692.6075370855006, 425.4782925339686, [...] ]

As you can see, all the neurons have the same weights.

I hope that I explained the issue well. If anybody has an idea about why it is doing this and how I can fix it I would be grateful to them!

Comment: My guess is that KohonenNeuron.weight is static. We need more code to diagnose the issue. The toString() method of DefaultNetwork might be wrong too.

Comment: Your guess is right! I have been looking for a static variable origin for the problem and I don't know how I couldn't see this one.I fixed it and It worked just fine. Thank you! When I started working with this library I realized that almost all the variable are declared statically. I thought I changed them all, apparently not.